# How to throw a predefined exception that inform the parameter name, the argument value, and predefined system error message?

Tags: c#

### Description

If I use the following constructor of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` class, the exception will inform the parameter name that causes the exception, along with a **predefined system error message**:

```
public ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string paramName)
```

Alternatively, if I use the following constructor, the exception will inform the parameter name, the argument value, and the **specified error message**:

```
public ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string paramName, object actualValue, string message)
```

### Question

How to throw a predefined exception that inform the parameter name, the argument value, along with a **predefined system error message**?

I'm not confident with this one:

```
public static int Test(int Number)
{
  ArgumentOutOfRangeException argEx = new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
  throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Number", Number, argEx.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom exception derived from the ArgumentOutOfRangeException and as many parameters as you want.

```
public class ExtendedArgumentOutOfRangeException : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
{
    public string SystemMessage { get; }

    public ExtendedArgumentOutOfRangeException(string message, string value, string systemMessage) : base(message, value)
    {
        SystemMessage = systemMessage;
        // more here
    }
}
```